# Can't successfully convert to int/float within average calculation in python

Tags: python, input, average

Here is my code, without the last part it splits the name and score. I'm trying to work out the average by using sum/len. I need to convert the score to float somewhere, whenever I try I get the following message:

```
for name in sorted(user_scores):

    # get the highest score in the list.
    average = sum(user_scores[name])/len[name]

    print(name, average)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your average calculation is wrong. It should be

```
average = sum(user_scores[name]) / len(user_scores[name])
```

(Probably this was some kind of copy-paste error. With `len[name]` you are using `name` as an index to `len`, not as a parameter (hence the `not subscriptable` error), and with `len(name)` you would divide by the number of characters in the name.)

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Nowhere in your code are you using `+`, so I assume you removed it.  The problem would be that you are trying to add an `int` and `str` (string) and Python does not know if you want to add two values or concatenate two strings.  Solve this by converting one to the same type as the other.  If `a` is an `int` and `b` a `str`:

```
a + int(b)
```

or

```
str(a) + b
```

The message:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

This is from:

```
len[name]
```

`len` is a function, and to call a function you must use parentheses, not square brackets.

```
len(name)
```

However, as @tobias_k states, the calculation for average is wrong anyway,

Answer (score 0):

What @tobias_k and @cdarke said are more than correct. In addition though to their answers, you need to typecast either the numerator or the denominator to float in order to get a float result:
eg.
     average = sum(user_scores[name])/ float(len(user_scores[name]))

Comment: Good point, but probably not necessary. OP uses `print(...)`, so that's probably on Python 3, where floating point division is the default.